# Gradient function of $y=5e^{3x}-6e^{-6x}$

Tags: calculus

This question is asking me to find the gradient function, $y'$ of the equation $y=5e^{3x}-6e^{-6x}$

I thought it was as simple as having $y=15e^{3x} - 36e^{-6x}$, however this isn't the gradient function. What am I doing so horribly wrong?

(yes, I'm really new to calculus).

Thanks!

Comment: As a point of reference, the gradient is only the same as the derivative when considering functions of one variable. In multiple variables, the gradient is a vector of [partial derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative).

Answer (score 1):

In this case the gradient is the derivative because there is only one variable.

By the way,

$$y' = 15{e^{3x}} + 36{e^{ - 6x}}.$$

Define what you mean by the gradient function.

Comment: Sorry, that's the way the question phrased "find the derivative" :P Thanks, so I was right initially?

Comment: Almost because $y' = 15{e^{3x}} + 36{e^{ - 6x}}$.

Comment: Oh, right, thanks! :)